# How to get 2 fragments in a single activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to use fragments in android and want to display `fragment1`  and `fragment2` together but with this code I am just getting the second fragment . How to get both fragments?

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();



                Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, f1);
               Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, f2);

        ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to show 2 fragments ? One above another ? Please explain in details.

Answer (score 4):

Try this logic:

in your main activity layout add two `framelayout`: one after another

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your activity you can add both the fragment using:

```
Fragment1 one = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 two = new Fragment2();

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, one, "fragmentone").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, two, "fragmenttwo").commit();
```

Comment: when I am using           fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, one, "fragmentone").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, two, "fragmenttwo").commit();                                                                      
then the app is running but when i am using                  
 FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction(); 
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, one, "fragmentone").commit();
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, two, "fragmenttwo").commit();                    then app is crashing .Why?

Comment: i did not understand what you mean to say...........what is fragment transaction version

Comment: check if you are using v4 version? also post the crash log..it is not easy to know the crash reason without the log..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```